# How do I properly apply a border-radius to a table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I've long used the simple method for applying border-radius to tables, which is looking for each corner cell and applying the radius for that corner to each of those cells, like so:

```css
table > :first-child > tr:first-of-type > :first-child { border-radius: 5px 0 0 0 }
table > :first-child > tr:first-of-type > :last-child { border-radius: 0 5px 0 0 }
table > :last-child > tr:last-of-type > :first-child { border-radius: 0 0 0 5px }
table > :last-child > tr:last-of-type > :last-child { border-radius: 0 0 5px 0 }
```

Now, this works all fine and dandy for your *average* table which is a perfect grid of rows and columns with no random row-spans or column-spans. But, what happens when you start including those? It messes everything up. Take, for example, this table where the last row only has a single cell in it, where the next three are spanned from the previous row:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Item 1</td>
        <td rowspan="2">Description for both Item 1 and Item 2</td>
        <td rowspan="2">Option for Items 1 & 2</td>
        <td rowspan="2">Option for Items 1 & 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Item 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What happens here is that the *bottom-right* border radius get applied to that single "Item 2" cell because it's both the first and last child in the last row, and the bottom-right corner ends up overriding it.

[image: Table border radius]

This would be easy to fix if it were a column-span issue, as I could just add another line below that CSS for `:only-child` which would apply both the bottom-left and bottom-right radius to that single item. But what about when it's a row-span that's throwing it off?

How can I account for row-spans and apply the appropriate border-radius to each corner of a table?

Comment: Is the HTML fixed? Can you add classnames onto the DOM elements? That would really simplify things here.

Comment: @JMWhittaker: Occasionally it's generated, which is why I've been avoiding class names. But I suppose I could add in some sort of manual override for the edge-cases like this. The generated ones should never have any kind of row-span, so maybe I could just add a class to the table for non-generated ones if border-radius shouldn't be applied automatically and should instead be applied by class at each corner... That sounds simple enough.

Answer (score -1):

You could try using attribute selectors. Maybe something like this

```
table > :last-child > tr:last-of-type > :only-child { border-radius: 0 0 0 5px }
table > :first-child > tr:first-of-type > :last-child[rowspan="2"]{border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0}
```

that makes both right corners round on the last `td` of first row, if it spans over both lines.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x4VTS/)

This way you can tell if `rowspan` is applied to a `td`, however with more complex and changing table structure, structural selectors might not be the best solution, and you might want to use class selectors.

Comment: It really sucks that there's no better way to round tables! I'm trying to hide cells and so I then need to use JS to calculate the first visible element and apply a class to that. Seems like the spec needs to change...